# strech image into hex picturebox arry

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I made a grid of hex pictureboxes.
I load them using bitmap.
I call them trough running time (mypic arry)
what I want is to get into every hex a full picture (of sheep in this example)
what I get is that every hex is a pixel or part  from the big picture
I tried to set the picture size mode to strech zoom etc. but it doesn't work
0

the problem is in the shape extention when i use a simple picturebox its work fine

''' Option Strict On

Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module hexagon

<Extension()> _
Public Sub Shape(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal side As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim ShortSide As Integer = CInt(System.Math.Sin(30 * System.Math.PI / 180) * side)
Dim LongSide As Integer = CInt(System.Math.Cos(30 * System.Math.PI / 180) * side)

Dim Points(5) As Point
Points(0) = New Point(x, y)
Points(1) = New Point(x + LongSide, y + ShortSide)
Points(2) = New Point(x + LongSide, y + ShortSide + side)
Points(3) = New Point(x, y + ShortSide * 2 + side)
Points(4) = New Point(x - LongSide, y + ShortSide + side)
Points(5) = New Point(x - LongSide, y + ShortSide)


Dim MyPath As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath

For i = 0 To 4
    MyPath.AddLine(Points(i), Points(i + 1))
Next
MyPath.AddLine(Points(5), Points(0))
MyPath.CloseFigure()
ctrl.Region = New Region(MyPath)
MyPath.Dispose()
```

End Sub
End Module

'''

[image]

Comment: What is a hex picturebox? Is it a control you downloaded from somewhere, or your own custom control? Please also provide a minimal reproducible code sample.

Comment: its a control i download. it basicly behave like a regular picture box. i load it in the form load event.

Comment: Dim myPic As New PictureBox()
                myPic.Shape(hexRib - 2, hPoint.X, hPoint.Y + 2)
                myPic.Name = Xline1 & "x" & yCount
                myPic.Parent = Me.Panel1
myPic.Size = New Size(1000, 1000)
                myPic.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                myPic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
                Panel1.Controls.Add(myPic)

Comment: @IdanAzari Could you give us a link to the download? Then we can try it ourselves.

Comment: i can send you the project. i dont remember where i download

Comment: i added in the answer below

Comment: i found the link https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19859.vb-net-how-to-make-an-oval-triangle-pentagon-hexagon-or-octagon-for-a-control-or-a-form.aspx?Sort=MostRecent&PageIndex=1

Comment: i took this code and refit it to my program as you can see in the answer section. i see that the problem is when i load another hex its doesnt show so i have to set the size of the image to something big (new size(1000,1000). that cause when i load the picture to the hex to see only the part that the hex cover.

Answer (score 0):

ok
so the problem were somewhere in while loop that i made.
didnt succeed to figure out why.
however i use now for loop to load the picture and its work fine ( for now 5 5 )
[fix picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/869Ki.jpg)